# creating filter by fields

Tags: views

I'm having a content type publications and researchers associated with these publications. I want to create a filter by the name of the researchers.  I created a relationship in the view, and I created a contextual filter, but it's not working. 
Right, now the filter is not showed in the view. If I create a sort criteria based on the researcher it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I create a entity relationship between in both content types, by creating a content type reference. Then, in the view I created a relationship the user. I created a contextual filter in the view using the user name.